# Having trouble completing the square for $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have $4x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2$. How would I get that to be of form $s^2 + t^2$??

In this example, the solution says it's $(2x - y)^2 + 3y^2$. How did we get that answer?

edit: Second term is negative, should be $4x^2 - 4xy + 4y^2$

Comment: That's funny: I get $(2x+y)^2+3y^3$.

Comment: It can be obtained by diagonalizing the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown OH whoops the second term is supposed to be negative

Comment: So $-4xy$ instead of $+4xy$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes

Comment: Then the term is $(x-2y)^2$ of course.

Comment: @choco_addicted If you mean diagonalizing by computing eigenvalues and so forth, that rarely produces the same result as successively completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2-4xy+4y^2=4x^2-4xy+y^2+3y^2=(2x-y)^2+3y^2$$
You should try to use this :
  $$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to complete the square when there is only one variable?  Then you can complete it when there are two variables by ignoring the second variable at first.  In fact, since this is a homogeneous polynomial, you can complete the square by ignoring the second variable entirely!

So instead of $ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x y + 4 y ^ 2 $, consider $ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x + 4 $.  Hopefully you can do that on your own, but I'll walk through it in this paragraph, just in case.  Now, I generally factor out the leading coefficient (although in this case it's probably easier not to, since that coefficient is a perfect square), to get $ 4 ( x ^ 2 - x + 1 ) $.  (This would introduce fractions if the coefficients weren't all multiples of $ 4 $.)  Then focussing on the factor $ x ^ 2 - x + 1 $, ignore the constant term for now and think of how you would get $ x ^ 2 - x $ by expanding a square $ ( x + p ) ^ 2 $.  It would expand to $ x ^ 2 + 2 p x $ (plus a constant term), so $ 2 p = - 1 $, or $ p = - 1 / 2 $.  That is, our square will be $ ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 $.  Now paying attention to the constant terms, this expands to $ x ^ 2 - x + 1 / 4 $, so we introduce $ 1 / 4 - 1 / 4 $.  That is, $ x ^ 2 - x + 1 $ becomes $ x ^ 2 - x + 1 / 4 - 1 / 4 + 1 = ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 / 4 $.  Now restoring the factor of $ 4 $, we get $ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x + 4 = 4 ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + 4 ( 3 / 4 ) = 4 ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 $.  I would generally leave it like that, but if you want it explicitly in the form $ s ^ 2 + t ^ 2 $, then you can write $ 4 $ as $ 2 ^ 2 $ and $ 3 $ as $ ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 $ to get $ 2 ^ 2 ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 = ( 2 x - 1 ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 $.  In summary, $$ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x + 4 = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x + 1 ) = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x + 1 / 4 - 1 / 4 + 1 ) = 4 \bigl ( ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 / 4 \bigr ) = 4 ( x - 1 / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 = ( 2 x - 1 ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 \text . $$  So that completes the square if there are no $ y $s.

Now stick the $ y $s back in.  So $$ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x y + 4 y ^ 2 = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 ) = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 / 4 - y ^ 2 / 4 + y ^ 2 ) = 4 \bigl ( ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 / 4 \bigr ) = 4 ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 = ( 2 x - y ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 \, y ) ^ 2 \text . $$  That's the final answer in the form $ s ^ 2 + t ^ 2 $.

You can also do the original expression with the $ y $s, but remember that your focus is on $ x $.  So nearly repeating my second paragraph above, I again start by factoring out the coefficient on $ x ^ 2 $ to get $ 4 ( x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 ) $.  Then focussing on the factor $ x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 $, ignore the non-$ x $ term for now and think of how you would get $ x ^ 2 - x y $ by expanding a square $ ( x + p ) ^ 2 $.  It would expand to $ x ^ 2 + 2 p x $ (plus a non-$ x $ term), so $ 2 p = - y $, or $ p = - y / 2 $.  That is, our square will be $ ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 $.  Now paying attention to the non-$ x $ terms, this expands to $ x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 / 4 $, so we introduce $ y ^ 2 / 4 - y ^ 2 / 4 $.  That is, $ x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 $ becomes $ x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 / 4 - y ^ 2 / 4 + y ^ 2 = ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 / 4 $.  Now restoring the factor of $ 4 $, we get $ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x y + 4 y ^ 2 = 4 ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 4 ( 3 y ^ 2 / 4 ) = 4 ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 $.  Again, I would generally leave it like that, but if you want it explicitly in the form $ s ^ 2 + t ^ 2 $, then you can write $ 4 $ as $ 2 ^ 2 $ and $ 3 $ as $ ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 $ to get $ 2 ^ 2 ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 ) ^ 2 y ^ 2 = ( 2 x - y ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 \, y ) ^ 2 $.  In summary, $$ 4 x ^ 2 - 4 x y + 4 y ^ 2 = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 ) = 4 ( x ^ 2 - x y + y ^ 2 / 4 - y ^ 2 / 4 + y ^ 2 ) = 4 \bigl ( ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 / 4 \bigr ) = 4 ( x - y / 2 ) ^ 2 + 3 y ^ 2 = ( 2 x - y ) ^ 2 + ( \sqrt 3 \, y ) ^ 2 \text . $$  And that's the same as I got in the previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The orthogonalization of $f(x,y)$ is required wherein it can be written as sum of two perfect square.

Let us use $$x=X\cos t -Y \sin \theta, y=X\sin \theta +Y \cos \theta ~~~~(1)$$ in the given quadratic
$$f(x,y)=ax^2+c y^2+bxy=a[XC-YC)^2+c(XS+YC)^2+b(XC-YC)(XS+YC),$$
where $C=\cos \theta, S=\sin \theta$, then
$$f(x,y)=(aC^2+bCS+cS^2)X^2+(aS^2-bCS+CC^2) Y^2,$$ if $$\tan 2\theta=\frac{b}{a-c}.$$ From (1) it follows that $X=Cx+Sy, Y=-Sx+Cy$
So $$f(x,y)=P(\theta)~(Cx+Sy)^2+Q(\theta)~ (-Sx+Cy)^2,$$
where  $$P(\theta)=(aC^2+bCS+cS^2), ~Q(\theta)=(aS^2-bCS+cC^2)$$

Comment: That's not a sum of squares: also one of the $x$s should be $xy$.

Comment: In fact orthogonalization of $f(x,y)$ is required which I do in this edit.

Answer (score 0):

The $4x^2$ suggests strongly you need $(2x+ay)^2$. This will have as its cross term $2(2x)(ay)=4axy$ and we need $4xy$ so take $a=1$. We then have $1$ $x^2$ from this term and $3x^2$ left.

So $(2x+y)^2 + 3x^2$ will do which equals $s^2+t^2$ for $s=2x+y$ and $t=\sqrt{3}x$.

We could also start with the $4y^2$ term and get $(2x+y)^2 + 3y^2$ and a very similar solution.

Comment: See I still don't get that strong suggestion, I can't look at that and think of the $(2x + ay)^2$. Can you try doing it if all the coefficients are 1?

Comment: @ming yes, $(x + \frac12 y)^2 + \frac34y^2$. E.g.

Answer (score 0):

If you know complex numbers, solving $4x^2-4xy+4y^2=0$ for $x$ gives $x=y(1\pm i\sqrt{3})/2$, so$$4x^2-4xy+4y^2=4(x-y/2+iy\sqrt{3}/2)(x-y/2-iy\sqrt{3}/2)=4((x-y/2)^2+3y^2/4)=(2x-y)^2+3y^2.$$